# ipython kernel is not working in spyder of anaconda3 newly installed on my windows 10 laptop. It is displaying an error

Tags: python, anaconda, ipython, jupyter, spyder

`Ipython kernel` is not working in `spyder` of `anaconda3` newly installed on my Windows10 laptop. It is displaying an error,

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\viswa\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole.py", line 1572, in create_kernel_manager_and_kernel_client
>   kernel_manager.start_kernel(stderr=stderr_handle)
>   File "C:\Users\viswa\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 240, in start_kernel
>   self.write_connection_file()
>   File "C:\Users\viswa\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 547, in write_connection_file
>   kernel_name=self.kernel_name
>   File "C:\Users\viswa\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 212, in write_connection_file
>   with secure_write(fname) as f:
>   File "C:\Users\viswa\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in **enter**
>   return next(self.gen)
>   File "C:\Users\viswa\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 102, in secure_write
>   with os.fdopen(os.open(fname, open_flag, 0o600), mode) as f:
>   PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\viswa\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernelc3fe9d0071.json'

Comment: "Permission denied" error seems to be what triggered this, and the triggering process was "secure_write" to an os directory, which implies that some necessary process did not have admin write permissions. Maybe it did not run under an admin account? That's all I can discern from this traceback, but I have not used ipython before so someone else may have more insight.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this you need to update the jupyter_client package, with the following command:

```
conda update jupyter_client
```

Comment: your welcome. which part did help you? running as administrator?

Comment: I edited the answer to avoid the advice of running Spyder as admin (because it could be really dangerous) and using pip to update `jupyter_client`, which is totally unnecessary when using Anaconda.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. Though I think running anaconda as administrator helped @ViswaKoduru (Didn't?)